# How to Read Json Collection From File Using Json.Net in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have this json file :

```
{
   “transactions”:[
      {
         “type”:”deposit”,
         “account_id”:123456789012345,
         “amount”:20000.0
      },
      {
         “type”:”deposit”,
         “account_id”:555456789012345,
         “amount”:20000.0
      },
      {
         “type”:”payment”,
         “account_id”:123456789012345,
         “amount”:20000.0
      },
      {
         “type”:”transfer”,
         “from”:555456789012345,
         “to”:123456789012345,
         “amount”:20000.0
      }
   ]
}
```

and I want to read this file with JSON.net.

I tried this code but it has some unhandeld errors :

```
var records = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Type>>(File.ReadAllText(FileAddress));
using (StreamReader SrFile = File.OpenText(FileAddress))
{
    JsonSerializer Serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    JsonAccount newJsonAccount = (JsonAccount)Serializer.Deserialize(SrFile, typeof(JsonAccount));
}
```

the error is :

> An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Additional information: Unexpected character encountered while parsing
>   value: �. Path '', line 0, position 0

now it has this error :

Additional information: Error converting value "transactions" to type 'ImportAndExport.MainForm+JsonAccount'. Path '', line 1, position 14.

UPDATE 2 :

now the error is :

```
    An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Additional information: Invalid character after parsing property name. Expected ':' but got: t. Path '', line 2, position 7.
```

Comment: Where are you using `var records` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error:

> ```
> Additional information: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: �. Path '', line 0, position 0.
> ```

Is probably caused by your using curly quotes instead of straight quotes. Replace it with standard straight quotes.

EDIT:

In case you get more issues with JSON parsing, this is how I would parse that JSON:

```
         string jsonString = @"{
    ""transactions"": [
        {
            ""type"": ""deposit"",
            ""account_id"": 123456789012345,
            ""amount"": 20000
        },
        {
            ""type"": ""deposit"",
            ""account_id"": 555456789012345,
            ""amount"": 20000
        },
        {
            ""type"": ""payment"",
            ""account_id"": 123456789012345,
            ""amount"": 20000
        },
        {
            ""type"": ""transfer"",
            ""from"": 555456789012345,
            ""to"": 123456789012345,
            ""amount"": 20000
        }
    ]
}";

        var recordObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
```

If I wanted to get the last transaction

```
        var lastRecord = JObject.Parse(jsonString)["transactions"].Last()
```

If I wanted the deposit records

```
        var deposits = from transactions in JObject.Parse(jsonString)["transactions"]
                       where transactions["type"].ToString().Equals("deposit")
                       select transactions;
```

Comment: Please tell me more about it ... I can not understand

Comment: instead of `“type”:”deposit”` it should be `"type":"deposit"`. You should replace all instances of `“` and `”` with `"`

Comment: Thank you very much. But there is another error ! See update2

Comment: That seems like a bad JSON format error. Go to http://jsonlint.com/ and paste your JSON there and see if it validates :)